# BigQuery connector for excel - Request failed: Error. Unable to execute query. Timeout while fetching URL

Tags: excel, timeout, google-bigquery

I am trying to pull data from BigQuery into Excel.
when i run simple and fast queries, everything runs fine. when running "heavy" query that takes long to retrieve i get the following error:

Request failed: Error. Unable to execute query. Timeout while fetching URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{my-project}/queries.

the query i can see the query and retrieve its results in the browser tool query history.
I manage to retrieve data for simpler queries.

any ideas?

I would believe it has to do with default time out configuration. is there a way to set the timeout parameters for the connector?

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: If you run these queries in the bigquery web ui (http://bigquery.cloud.google.com), how long do they take? The connector uses appengine, which has some fairly strict timeouts.

Comment: Related, how long does Excel take before the timeout occurs?

Comment: query takes quite long ~8-10 minutes

Comment: excel timeout after ~1 minute

Comment: updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the bigquery web connector was not setting a timeout correctly. We have currently updated it to 60 seconds from 15 seconds. 60 seconds is the longest timeout we can use without major restructuring is because the connector is hosted in an appengine app.

Your 8-10 minute query, unfortunately, will not work. One alternative may be to run the query yourself and save the result in a bigquery table (i.e. set a destination table for the query) and then just read that table from excel (i.e. select *).

Comment: Thanks, i have posted a request on http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=48&thanks=48&ts=1383204957